# Web development workflow with svn

Tags: svn, workflow, assembla

I set up my svn in assembla, and I code and test on my local machine that is set up identical to the production server. THen, I commit changes to assembla svn and also ftp upload to my production server.

How can I improve my workflow? I would like to keep my svn on assembla because I can often move to another production server.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to build nant or MSBuild script that will do all dirty work automated. Those scripts also can ftp upload.

I've using on production server script to checkout last changes from svn, build and sync with production folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with interpreted languages like PHP, Python or Ruby for example, you can do a clean [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) directly from your repository to the production server, instead of uploading by ftp the source files from your machine.

You'll need shell access to your production server.